# Accessing the SensorDump API - Android

Tags: android

Has anyone worked on the SensorDump Android app before? I'm trying to get Accelerometer values from my phone and I've been able to dump it in to a CSV file on my computer. However, I'd like to add a timestamp to my values as well and SensorDump doesn't provide for that.

I can't find any documentation online ,and I was wondering if anyone had tried to modify it, or if there's any other app out there that does the same (i.e. lets me write Sensor Values onto a file, with timestamp).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own sensor dumper, in an activity with something like this in the onCreate:

```
    mStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
        try {
                    f = new FileWriter("/sdcard/download/sensorlog.txt");
                    if (f != null) {
                        f.append("time;value0;value1;value2\r\n");
                    }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot open sensorlog file..");
    }


mSensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mStepListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {  
        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

            Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
            if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

                double value0 = event.values[0];
                double value1 = event.values[1];
                double value3 = event.values[2];

                long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - mStartTime;


                try {
                    if (f != null) {
                        f.append(time+";"+value0+";"+value1+";"+value2 + "\r\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Cannot write to file");
                }

            }
        }

    };
```

This will give you a csv text file, with a timestamp and the 3 values.

ps. Don't forget to ask for SD-card write permission.

Also declare this first:

```
    FileWriter f;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private SensorEventListener mStepListener;
```

And don't forget to close the file..

```
try {
    f.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Cannot close file");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just a follow-up question, what does uptimeMillis() return? The time since start of execution? Is there an equivalent function in C#? (since I'm using another sensor which only has a C# API)

Comment: uptimeMillis gives you the milliseconds since booting. But since you save the starting point and substract the current time, the time saved in the CSV file is the number of milliseconds since the beginning of the measurement.
(And don't forget to accept the answer if it answer your question ;))